# How to retrieve values from XML and insert them into Dynamic SQL statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to take some XML and use its values within a dynamic SQL query.

So my XML may look like this:

```
DECLARE @xmlTest xml;
SET @xmlTest = '<Mapping>
    <Element name="FirstTable">
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn1</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn1</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn2</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn2</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn3</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn3</Destination>
        </Column>           
    </Element>
    <Element name="SecondTable">
            <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn4</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn4</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn5</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn5</Destination>
        </Column>
    </Element>
</Mapping>'
```

Using this XML, I want to map data from one table to another based on the Element "name" attribute. There are tables set up in the database based on the "names" ( ex: the database contains tables named "FirstTable" and "SecondTable")

There are other tables in the database that contain the  fields from the `<Column>` element. These are the tables from which I want to take certain columns and copy into the Element name tables. These tables contain only raw data that I wish to move into the other tables(like "FirstTable" and "SecondTable").

So an example of a SQL statement I would try to make is this:

```
INSERT INTO [FirstTable](DestinationColumn1, DestinationColumn2, DestinationColumn3)
SELECT (SourceColumn1, SourceColumn2, SourceColumn3)
FROM [RawDataTable]
```

I would need to execute this statement to insert into each table in which there are `<Column>` elements.

How would I get the values I need from the XML and into the SQL queries? Also, what is the best way to have this SQL statement run for each `<Element>` in the XML? Note: There will likely be varying amounts of `<Column>` elements, so I chose to use Dynamic SQL.

Thanks

Comment: You want to read xml in any programming eg. C# and then insert into SQL?

Comment: @ThitLwinOo the XML is generated from C# and sent to SQL where I want to map everything to the appropriate table based on the XML. The C# does the mapping and creates the XML, but I need that to reflect in the database tables.

Comment: Your db is SQL Server? I am unable to test as I don't have sql db on my PC. Have you checked the url? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx

Comment: @ThitLwinOo Yes, my db is SQL Server. The problem isn't how to parse through the XML, its how to specifically get the data I need from XML into a string so that I can insert that into a dynamic SQL statement. I already looked into the SQL XML data type methods. And yes, I have already visited that url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If C# code is generating the XML, it could also generate the SQL statements much easier. This probably isn't going to be efficient but you could use something like

```
DECLARE @xmlTest xml;
SET @xmlTest = '<Mapping>
    <Element name="FirstTable">
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn1</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn1</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn2</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn2</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn3</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn3</Destination>
        </Column>           
    </Element>
    <Element name="SecondTable">
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn4</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn4</Destination>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Source>SourceColumn5</Source>
            <Destination>DestinationColumn5</Destination>
        </Column>
    </Element>
</Mapping>'

;With Map
As
(
    SELECT
         x.value('../@name', 'nvarchar(50)') TableName
        ,x.value('Source[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') SourceColumn
        ,x.value('Destination[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') DestinationColumn
    from
        @xmlTest.nodes('/Mapping/Element/Column') T(x)
)
select distinct 'INSERT INTO [' + M.TableName + '] (' + Left(DC.DestinationColumns, Len(DC.DestinationColumns) - 1) + ') SELECT (' + Left(SC.SourceColumns, Len(SC.SourceColumns) - 1) + ') FROM [RawDataTable]' as SQLs
from Map M
cross apply (
    select
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), SourceColumn) + ',' AS [text()]
    from
        Map M2
    where
        M.TableName = M2.TableName
    FOR XML PATH('')
) SC(SourceColumns)
cross apply (
    select
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DestinationColumn) + ',' AS [text()]
    from
        Map M2
    where
        M.TableName = M2.TableName
    FOR XML PATH('')
) DC(DestinationColumns)
```

Comment: Excellent! This works great for me. As you said, its not the most efficient, but I decided to do it this way to keep consistent with some other stuff.